# WCF between WinForms applications

Tags: winforms, wcf

I have two `WinForms` applications that need to communicate.

I'm thinking about using `WCF` to establish communication between those two, but converting one of them `WCF` service application is not an option.

Is there a way to implement the `WCF` somehow or should I forget about it?

For example I thought of creating a `WCF` server (with `Push` and `Pull` mechanisms) that both applications could use, but I don't think it's very efficient.

Moreover, consider that the users cannot have administrative privileges, if this helps proposing other solutions.

Comment: Have you looked into self-hosted WCF services? There's an enormous amount of flexiblity in how you implement/wrap them.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is create an WCF service hosted in a Winform or an Console application. Than you should add the WCF service reference to your Winform applications References. Rest is simple. You may query the service in a timer say 500ms. This whole consept may help you. If you want to see an implemented example see the link below:

Have you seen: http://wcfsimplechat.codeplex.com/ . This little WCF Chat sample can help i think.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, the problem has already been solved. However, if my implementation matches the "WCF Chat" one, I'll accept your answer. If not, I'll post the implemented solution. I just need a couple of days to reach the code.